# Different invariants of group actions from isomorphic subgroups

Tags: group-actions, invariant-theory

Consider $D_8,$ the dihedral group of order $8$, acting on the unit square $X=[0,1]^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ in the natural way– essentially take the unique linear extension of the action on the vertices. Clearly any subgroup $H \le D_8$ also acts on $X$.

Say we want to study the invariants of the the action of some $H \le D_8$ on $X,$ i.e. we want to know what are the elements $x\in X$ such that $h.x = x$ for all $h \in H$. The set of all such $x \in X$ is denoted by $X_H$. What can we say about these invariants? Since $D_8$ is small we can just enumerate each of the subgroups and write down the invariants. Let's go ahead and do this, then I'll make some observations. In what follows let $f$ be a reflection about the vertical line $x=\tfrac{1}{2}$ and let $r$ be a rotation by $\pi/2$.

- Subgroups of order 1: $H = \{e\} \implies X_H = X$.
- Order 2:

  - (Vertical reflection) $H_1 = \{e, f\} \implies X_{H_1} = \{(x,y) \in X \mid x = \tfrac{1}{2}\}$
  - (Horizontal reflection) $H_2 = \{e, r^2f\} \implies X_{H_2} = \{(x,y) \in X \mid y = \tfrac{1}{2}\}$
  - (Right Diagonal Reflection) $H_3 = \{e, rf\} \implies X_{H_3} = \{(x,y) \in X \mid x = y\}$
  - (Left Diagonal Reflection) $H_4 = \{e, r^3f\} \implies X_{H_4} = \{(x,y) \in X \mid x+y = 1\}$
  - (Rotation by $\pi$) $H_5 = \{e, r^2\} \implies X_{H_5} = \{(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2})\}$
- Order 4:

  - Every subgroup of order $4$ contains $r^2$ and so the for any $H$ of order $4$ (or of order $8$, i.e. the whole group), we must have $X_H = \{(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2})\}$.

Here's what's bugging me. All the groups of order 2 are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2,$ but while the invariants of $H_1, H_2, H_3,$ and $H_4$ are all topologically the same, the invariants of $H_5$ suddenly drop by an extra dimension. So despite the fact that "group theoretically" we have the same group acting on $X$ in each case, the invariants are topologically different– the groups themselves don't tell us enough information about the action. The "problem" with $H_5$ is that it's the action of a vertical reflection combined with a horizontal reflection, so it "cuts down" the dimension of the invariants by two. My questions then are twofold.

1. What exactly is the missing piece of "topological information" here? And importantly, what is the right language to use to talk about this? I know group invariants are somehow related to cohomology groups, but this is outside of my scope of expertise.
2. Is there something we can say about the relationship between the size of $H$ and the dimension (or some other topological feature) of $X_H$ in general (i.e. suppose instead of a square we wanted to think about a hypercube).

Any insight would be much appreciated.